# How to display a placeholder in MUI Select component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to apply a placeholder "Select a brand" in the select, but I can't.
I've tried several options but without any success.
This is the code:

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
          <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-name-label" sx={{ color:'inherit' }}>Brand</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-multiple-name-label"
            id="demo-multiple-name-label"
            label="Brand"
            value={certificateData.brandName || ''}
            onChange={(e) => void setCertificateData((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, brandName: e.target.value }))}
          >
            {brands
              .sort((a, b) => a.brandName.localeCompare(b.brandName))
              .map((brand) => (
                <MenuItem key={brand.brandNumber} value={brand.brandName}>
                  {brand.brandName}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
This is what I have so far:
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWEwU.png
```

Comment: Check the example here. Its using the state and if there is any selected value for the placeholder. https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#placeholder

Answer (score 0):

```
<FormControl>
    <InputLabel>Select a brand</InputLabel>
    <Select variant="outlined" size="small" fullWidth>
    <MenuItem value={1}>Option 1</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={2}>Option 2</MenuItem>
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution only changes the label on top (I don't want to change that) but not in the select as I'm showing in my picture.

Comment: how can I center this text?